# CSS Flexbox right align responsive

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

There is one CSS flexbox problem I'm trying to solve: right alignment of boxes.

So.. I have 4 divs in row. Two of them needs to be aligned left, and the rest needs to be on the right side. I know how to do this and this is not a problem (`margin-left: auto` on 3rd).

But they have property `flex-wrap: wrap` because I want them to wrap on small screens. I want 3rd and 4th div to be on the right side on every screen size. I can add `margin-left: auto` on 4th and it will create unwanted space between 3rd and 4th div, but it works for small screen (3rd and 4th stays on right).

I don't want to use media queries because divs width is dynamic...

Is there any nice solution for that? I don't want to give op on flexbox here!

Here is codepen: http://codepen.io/djkantoci/pen/XNxLVK

Red is with `margin-left: auto`, blue is without:
[image: Red is with margin-left: auto, blue is without]

Comment: i dont't get you man.. LoL.. so you wanted 4 dives, 1 and 2 align to left and the others align to right.  and the problem is? can you put an image what the page should be? don't put an image that i can see in your codepen.

Comment: What the page should look like is first big gray box, and last gray box on this image here. The problem is on second box where you can see "NO" in red box, and in 3rd box (small screen) where you see "NO" in blue box! I can't make it more simple with real problem image, it could be even more confusing... trust me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, added `justify-content: flex-end` and `margin-right: auto` to .f2 element:

```css
.flex {
  align-items: center;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.flex.small {
  width: 500px;
}

.f {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  text-align: center
}
.f2 {
  margin-right: auto
}
.f3 {
  flex-basis: 300px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="f f1">1</div>
  <div class="f f2">2</div>
  <div class="f f3">3</div>
  <div class="f f4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="flex small">
  <div class="f f1">1</div>
  <div class="f f2">2</div>
  <div class="f f3">3</div>
  <div class="f f4">4</div>
</div>
```

OK?

Comment: TNX! I don't know why I didn't think of that. I was to much focused on the right side :)

Comment: Welcome! It's so common to stick into one attribute or value :)

Comment: i found the problem on the other side now (I updated the pen on codepen)... When the screen gets too small for the first two divs and they wrap up, first one gets aligned to the right... :( flexbox should really have justify-self property...

Comment: For that small screens you can maybe use this small media query:

`.flex {flex-direction: column;}`
`.f1 {align-self: flex-start}`
`.f3, .f4 {align-self: flex-end}`

Comment: Yep... i knew i would eventually have to reach for media queries, i was hoping i'm just forgetting something :) Thanks again!